# Vigilar los cambios en ficheros automáticamente en grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, grunt, task-runner

Tengo **grunt** configurado en un proyecto de **angular** y es un rollo tener que ejecutarlo cada vez que quiero generar unos nuevos ficheros.

¿Hay alguna forma de que se ejecute automáticamente cada vez que haga un cambio en alguno?

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta tarea se puede llevar a cabo mediante el paquete [watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)

## 1. INSTALAR WATCH

Puedes instalarlo con:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch
```

## 2. DEFINIR WATCH EN GRUNT

Una vez instalado, definimos un objeto watch definido dentro del `Gruntfile.js`:

```
watch: {
    js: {
        files: [
            'assets/js/*.js',
            'assets/js/modules/*.js',
            'assets/js/controllers/*.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['uglify']
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, estoy vigilando **todos los ficheros .js** de las carpetas:

```
assets/js/
assets/js/modules/
assets/js/controllers/
```

**En cuanto detecte un cambio, ejecutará la tarea que desees**. En mi ejemplo ejecuta la tarea uglify.

## 3. EJECUTAR TAREA

En el punto anterior **le dijimos a grunt que ejecutase la tarea uglify**. Por si tienes curiosidad la definición es esta:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
    },
    build: {
        src: [
            'assets/js/vendor/jquery.js',
            'assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.js',
            'assets/js/vendor/angular.js',
            'assets/js/vendor/angular-route.js',
            'assets/js/modules/ejemploManager.js',
            'assets/js/controllers/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'assets/js/build/ejemplo.js'
    }
}
```

Lo que hace esta tarea uglify en concreto es **unificar todos los ficheros js en un único fichero** llamado `ejemplo.js`

Puedes instalar [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) con

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify
```

## 4. ACCEDER AL package.json

En options puedes ver que hace uso de una variable llamada `pkg.name`, esto es el nombre de mi aplicación definida en el `package.json`. Puedes leer el `package.json` desde grunt con esta definición:

```
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
```

## 5. DECLARAR PAQUETES EN GRUNT

Por último, recuerda que hay que declarar los paquetes npm en `Gruntfile.js` para que grunt los cargue y pueda acceder a ellos:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```

## 6. Bonus track: Tarea por defecto

Se puede definir una tarea por defecto en grunt tal que así:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
```

Ahora al ejecutar vía terminal

```
grunt
```

Se ejecutará la tarea `uglify`

## 7. EJECUTAR WATCH EN 2º PLANO

Finalmente dejaremos corriendo `watch` en segundo plano de forma que cada nuevo cambio hecho en los ficheros `.js` arriba mencionados ejecuten la tarea definida. Vamos a ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
grunt watch&
```

**Nota:** El `&` nos permitirá seguir ejecutando comandos en la terminal. Si prefieres dejar esa terminal sólo para watch entonces ejecuta `grunt watch`

## 8. Resultado final

El fichero `Gruntfile.js` ha quedado así:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: [
                    'assets/js/*.js',
                    'assets/js/modules/*.js',
                    'assets/js/controllers/*.js'
                ],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src: [
                    'assets/js/vendor/jquery.js',
                    'assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.js',
                    'assets/js/vendor/angular.js',
                    'assets/js/vendor/angular-route.js',
                    'assets/js/modules/ejemploManager.js',
                    'assets/js/controllers/*.js'
                ],
                dest: 'assets/js/build/ejemplo.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, voy a probar a configurarlo como indicas

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y funciona perfectamente lo que dices!

Answer (score 1):

Con [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) puedes hacer que se ejecuten las tareas de grunt a la que se detecte un cambio en los archivos o folders que decidas.

Tiene buena documentación y hay muchísimos ejemplos por Internet.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!